# C++ Using function with sprintf_s inside sprintf_s

Tags: c++, char, buffer

I want to **write data** into a char buffer. Therefore I have a **function to format my data**. As an example, I just pass an int value to the function like this:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

char* writeData(int iData, char* sBufferData){
    sprintf_s(sBufferData, 2048, "val:%i", iData);
    return sBufferData;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    char sBuffer[2048];
    char sBufferData[2048];

    sprintf_s(sBuffer, 2048, "%s, %s",
        writeData(1, sBufferData),
        writeData(2, sBufferData)
        );
    printf(sBuffer);

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

But the output result is: **val:1, val:1**

What I would like to have is: **val:1, val:2**

Can someone explain to me, why I get two times 1 as value in my final buffer?

Comment: Note that `val:2, val:2` would also be a possible outcome - C++ doesn't guarantee the order of evaluation, except that all function arguments are evaluated before the function is called. (And it's that rule which causes the observed behavior). On an unrelated note, prefer `std::string`. It would also have prevented this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char sBuffer[2048];
char sBufferData[2048];
sprintf_s(sBuffer, 2048, "%s, %s",
    writeData(1, sBufferData),
    writeData(2, sBufferData)
    );
```

You are reusing `sBufferData` for both calls of `writeData`. One call to the function overwrites the result of the other call before you get around to `sprintf_s`.

Add a separate buffer:

```
char sBuffer[2048];
char sBufferData1[2048];
char sBufferData2[2048];
sprintf_s(sBuffer, 2048, "%s, %s",
    writeData(1, sBufferData1),
    writeData(2, sBufferData2)
    );
```

Comment: It would be also nice to explain, why the output is `val:1, val:1` and not `val:2, val:2` - just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Because the compiler decided to compute the second call to `writeData` before the first call. It could have also decided to do it in the opposite order.